# Ambiguous reference to template class (C++)

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am new to template classes, and tried to implement a very simple program, just to try out the functionality and syntax.
I initialise a template class distance, and then try to get the data and display it.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>

class distance {

T feet;
T inches;

public:
    distance ()
    {

    }
T getdata (T f, T i)
{
    feet=f;
    inches=i;
}
void showdata ()
{
    cout<<"Distance is "<<feet<<" feet and "<<inches<<" inches";
}

};

int main ()

{

    distance <int> x;
    x.getdata(5,7);
    x.showdata();


}
```

However, on the `distance <int> x` line, I get the error stating 'error: reference to 'distance' is ambiguous'. I am not able to figure out my error.

Comment: Unable to reproduce your compilation error. This is obviously not the code that produces the compilation error. Your shown code fails to meet all requirements for a [mre], therefore nobody will be able to help you; at most you can expect are random guesses as to what the problem might be. Although I think I have a pretty good guess as to the common error that has this result, I cannot be sure, due your failure to provide a [mre], to confirm it.

Comment: I have edited it to include the header files and library that I used. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: Yes, and now this confirmed what I suspected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using namespace std;
```

You've just discovered [why `using namespace std;` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

This injects the C++ library's `std::distance` template into your program's global namespace, causing a name conflict with your own `distance` template.

Removing this, replacing all `cout`s with `std::cout`s, and fixing the return value from `getdata()` fixed all compilation errors.

Use this as a learning lesson: avoid `using namespace std;` in the future, or be prepared to deal with mysterious compilation errors.